# Dont see Debugger in Preferences/ IPython Console (or Python Console)

Tags: python, debugging, spyder

I am trying to find a way to disable debugger going into built-in functions. Is there a way to accomplish this? For some reason, I do not see a tab for the debugger in the preferences-> iPython console. Should there be one and how can I enable this? Thanks

Arun

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) What's your Spyder version?

Comment: I think version 3 which I had, did not have this functionality. I now downloaded the latest one 5.9 and it has this item in the menu. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. Downloaded the latest version of Spyder and it has this functionality. It appears my older version did not have this feature.